# RxJS - Keep a cache of the list and update the existing ones

Tags: javascript, typescript, websocket, rxjs

I have a WebSocket connection, that does 2 things:

- Sends on the first 'DATA' event the full List(i.e: 5 Items)
- On each next 'DATA' it sends information about the updated ones only.

I want to take that stream, process it, keep a cache of the items and do the following:

- Keep the existing list.
- If a new event arrives, and is in the list, update that based on an id(This should be generic enough).
- If it doesn't exist, add it to the list.

This is what I have done so far. Which isn't much. I am appending the items every time. Any help would be appreciated:

```js
function createCachedList$<T extends WSMessage<T>>(observable$: Observable<T>) {
  const INITIAL_STATE: any[] = [];

  const [fromDataPackets$, fromNonDataPackets$] = partition(
    observable$,
    (value) => value.type === WSMessageType.DATA
  );

  const pickDataPacket = fromDataPackets$.pipe(
    map((value: any) => value?.data),
    scan((prevState, currState: any[]) => {
      const nextState = R.uniq([...prevState, ...currState]);
      return [...prevState, ...nextState];
    }, INITIAL_STATE),
    tap((data: any) => console.log('Data:', data)),
    map((data: any) => ({ type: WSMessageType.DATA, data }))
  );

  return merge(pickDataPacket, fromNonDataPackets$);
}

export default createCachedList$;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems OK. `scan` is the operator I would use.

Probably you need to elaborate a bit the logic within `scan`. Something like this could help

```
scan((prevState, currState: any[]) => {
  currState.forEach(m => {
    const item = prevState.find(s => s.id === m.id);
    if (item) {
       Object.assign(item, m)
    } else {
       prevState.push(m)
    }
  });
  return prevState;
}, INITIAL_STATE),
```

Comment: I will accept your answer as it led me to the right conclusions. The problems I had was basically wrapping the results in one more array and second cause the object was nested only didn’t copy it it all. Had to use Ramada deepMergeRight to do it.